# Object initialization syntax in C++

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, delete-operator, object-initialization

I noticed a few strange errors when I was trying to initialize constructors. It's easiest if I just show them.

```
#include <iostream>


class MyClass {

public:

    int var1, var2, var3;

    MyClass() {

        var1, var2, var3 = 0;

    }

    MyClass(int one, int two, int three) {

        var1 = one;
        var2 = two;
        var3 = three;
    }

};


int main()
{
    MyClass object1(5, 6, 7);
    std::cout << object1.var1; // This works

    MyClass object2();
    std::cout << object2.var1; //Error object must have class type.

    MyClass object3 = MyClass();
    std::cout << object3.var1; //Now it works for some reason

    delete &object1;
    MyClass ojbect1(5, 6, 7); //error redefinition; multiple initialization
}
```

As you can see, for some reason, when I initialize object2, the values won't print unless, as with object3, the syntax is written as MyClass object3 = MyClass();

Furthermore when I delete object1 I have to use a & operator. This surprised me considering in this question  [Deleting an object in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428956/deleting-an-object-in-c) they don't use the ampersand.

Finally, when I try to re-initialize myobject, the compiler complains that there are multiple definitions. I tried leaving out the MyClass keyword and it still wouldn't allow it.

Now I can certainly make the program do what I want with various workarounds, but I don't understand *why* these things can't be done the way I wrote them here.

Comment: you create a `myobj2` but then you print ´myobj.var1´ is this typo?

Comment: o_O why are you trying to  `delete` a local variable?

Comment: Default initialization syntax looks like `MyClass obj;`, not `MyClass obj();`. The second one is actually a function that takes no parameters and returns `MyClass`.

Comment: Please recheck your code, it is not consistent with the errors you commented in. In particular the output statements.

Comment: C++ memory allocation works this way. You can explicitly delete what you have explicitly created, like "MyClass *ptr = new MyClass()". All automatic variables like "MyClass myObj;" are not yours. they are deleted automatically according to their lifetime. You always need to use pointers for delete.

Comment: If you want to destroy and reinitialize a variable with automatic storage: `MyType obj; obj.~MyType(); new (&obj) MyType();`

Comment: The reason they don't have to use `&` in the other question is that the argument to `delete` is a pointer variable, not a variable of class type.

Comment: Should we not close this as a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17060725/14065

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MyClass object2();
std::cout << object2.var1;
```

doesn't work since `object2` is parsed as "a function that takes no arguments and returns a `MyClass`". See
[Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

```
delete &object1;
```

is cause for undefined behavior. You can `delete` only objects that were created using `new`.

```
MyClass object1(5, 6, 7);
```

is a problem like the compiler told. You cannot redeclare the name in the same scope. If you want it have a new value, you can use:

```
object1 = MyClass(5, 6, 7);
```

Comment: the question has been edited, there were a couple typos in the code

Comment: Okay, that was working for a while, but now I overloaded the = operator and it is invoking an infinite loop in the copy constructor.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer, Please start a different question with that particular problem. As always, it is better if you can post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

```
MyClass myobj2();
```

Is not what you think it is. It declares a function named `myobj2` that returns a `MyClass`.

```
MyClass myobj(5, 6, 7);
```

Causes an error, because even if you delete `myobj` before, it is still declared to be of type `MyClass`. Deleting the object does not undeclare the variable. If you delete it and want to recreate it do this:

```
myobj = MyClass(5,6,7);
```

However, deleting a local object is nonsense. You dont have to delete an object that anyway will be deleted once it goes out of scope. Actually you should only `delete` objects that were created via `new`, otherwise you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: It's more than nonsense, it's UB.

Comment: @JamesRoot I was faster with typing than with thinking, I am happy that you didnt see the super nonsense first version of this answer ;)

Comment: @tobi303 I saw it :P I do the same, usually my answers get an average of about 5 edits before they make sense :)

Comment: question edited, there were a couple typos in the code

Comment: upvote. I now see the function syntax. My bad, I get confused sometimes between python, java and C/C++ syntax.

Comment: Why does MyClass myobject(...) work at all. Shouldn't it always be MyClass myobject = MyClass(...)

Comment: @bigcodeszzer If you want to declare a function that returns `MyClass` you have to write `MyClass myobject()` so it would be very bad if this would not work