# Should I stop using auto_ptr?

Tags: c++

I've recently started appreciating `std::auto_ptr` and now I read that it will be [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404115/is-auto-ptr-deprecated). I started using it for two situations:

- Return value of a factory
- Communicating ownership transfer

Examples:

```
// Exception safe and makes it clear that the caller has ownership.
std::auto_ptr<Component> ComponentFactory::Create() { ... }

// The receiving method/function takes ownership of the pointer. Zero ambiguity.
void setValue(std::auto_ptr<Value> inValue);
```

Despite the problematic copy semantics I find `auto_ptr` useful. And there doesn't seem to be an alternative for the above examples.

Should I just keep using it and later switch to `std::unique_ptr`? Or is it to be avoided?

Comment: I'd say stick with `auto_ptr` for whatever project you're working on, and switch whenever you start something new, so that you aren't  creating complexity by mixing them together.  (I'm assuming the compiler(s) you use support `unique_ptr`.)

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` is being deprecated not because it isn't useful, but because `std::unique_ptr` does everything it already does, just better.  So whether you switch to `std::unique_ptr` or not, there's no reason to stop using `std::auto_ptr`.

Comment: Eric Lippert wrote about this a long time ago. It's an interesting read: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/16/53016.aspx

Comment: @Mike: I don't really see how that applies. So COM refcounting is a mess, and he wrote some illegal code which just so happened to explode when he also involved (badly written) smart pointers. Hardly tells us much about *sane* smart pointer classes used in sane C++ code.

Comment: @jalf Hey, I dunno. I'm just adding some information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is so very very useful, despite it's flaws, that I'd highly recommend just continuing to use it and switching to `unique_ptr` when it becomes available.

`::std::unique_ptr` requires a compiler that supports rvalue references which are part of the C++0x draft standard, and it will take a little while for there to be really wide support for it.  And until rvalue references are available, `::std::auto_ptr` is the best you can do.

Having both `::std::auto_ptr` and `::std::unique_ptr` in your code might confuse some people.  But you should be able to search and replace for `::std::unique_ptr` when you decide to change it.  You may get compiler errors if you do that, but they should be easily fixable.  The top rated answer to [this question about replacing `::std::auto_ptr` with `::std::unique_tr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451099) has more details.

Comment: But stay consistent within one project. There is nothing worse than having two types that do the same thing but with different names.

Comment: Technically, `unique_ptr` is not a drop-in replacement for `auto_ptr`.  Among other things, it changes a possible runtime crash into a definite compiler error.  This is generally a good thing, so you'll probably want to do a find-replace once it is available, fixing any compiler errors this triggers.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451099

Comment: @Brian - Thank you for that link.  I will include your clarification and that link in my answer in the morning.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

deprecated doesn't mean it's going away, just that there will be a better alternative.

I'd suggest keeping using it on current code, but using the new alternative on new code (New programs or modules, not small changes to current code). Consistency is important

Comment: It does mean that it *might* go away at some point in the future though.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest you go use boost smart pointers.

Comment: They don't solve the same problem.  Boost is not the answer to everything, no matter how useful it is.

Comment: boost smart pointers bear certain overhead with them. shared_ptr does an extra memory allocation, intrusive_ptr requires an embedded counter. there is no good substitute for auto_ptr yet.

Comment: What Omni said.  None of boost's smart pointers support transfer of ownership, because the standard library already provides that functionality as well as is possible in the current standard.  If `std::auto_ptr` works, using either of boost's shared pointers is almost certainly a mistake [`boost::scoped_ptr` might suffice, but those situations are relatively limited]

Comment: I'm already using the boost smart pointers. For local and member variables I use scoped_ptr, for use in containers shared_ptr. However, these do not "communicate" ownership transfer.

Comment: @Maxim Yegorushkin - sometimes the extra allocation can be bypassed using boost::make_shared.