# std::auto_ptr to std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, auto-ptr, unique-ptr

With the new standard coming (and parts already available in some compilers), the new type `std::unique_ptr` is supposed to be a replacement for `std::auto_ptr`.

Does their usage exactly overlap (so I can do a global find/replace on my code (not that I would do this, but if I did)) or should I be aware of some differences that are not apparent from reading the documentation?

Also if it is a direct replacement, why give it a new name rather than just improve the `std::auto_ptr`?

Answer (score 241, accepted):

You cannot do a global find/replace because you can copy an `auto_ptr` (with known consequences), but a `unique_ptr` can only be moved. Anything that looks like

```
std::auto_ptr<int> p(new int);
std::auto_ptr<int> p2 = p;
```

will have to become at least like this

```
std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int);
std::unique_ptr<int> p2 = std::move(p);
```

As for other differences, `unique_ptr` can handle arrays correctly (it will call `delete[]`, while `auto_ptr` will attempt to call `delete`.

Comment: on the other hand, doing this find/replace will only result in compile errors, it won't silently break code as far as I can see. So it is safe to do, if you manually fix the compile errors afterwards

Comment: @jalf: Indeed, I can't think of a counter-example that would be well-defined with auto_ptrs and UB with unique_ptrs.

Comment: so it seems like unique_ptr is an enhancement of auto_ptr: support array & remove ambiguity

Answer (score 107):

`std::auto_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` are incompatible in someways and a drop in replacement in others.  So, no find/replace isn't good enough.  However, after a find/replace working through the compile errors should fix everything except weird corner cases.  Most of the compile errors will require adding a `std::move`.

- **Function scope variable:**
  100% compatible, as long as you don't pass it by value to another function.
- **Return type:**
  not 100% compatible but 99% compatible doesn't seem wrong.
- **Function parameter by value:**
  100% compatible with one caveat, `unique_ptr`s must be passed through a `std::move` call.  This one is simple as the compiler will complain if you don't get it right.
- **Function parameter by reference:**
  100% compatible.
- **Class member variable:**
  This one is tricky.  `std::auto_ptr`s copy semantics are evil.  If the class disallows copying then `std::unique_ptr` is a drop in replacement.  However, if you tried to give the class reasonable copy semantics, you'll need to change the `std::auto_ptr` handling code.  This is simple as the compiler will complain if you don't get it right.  If you allowed copying of a class with a `std::auto_ptr` member *without* any special code, then shame on you and good luck.

In summary, `std::unique_ptr` is an unbroken `std::auto_ptr`.  It disallows at compile time behaviors that were *often* errors when using a `std::auto_ptr`.  So if you used `std::auto_ptr` with the care it needed, switching to `std::unique_ptr` should be simple.  If you  relied on `std::auto_ptr`'s odd behavior, then you need to refactor your code anyway.

Comment: +1 for "you need to refactor your code anyway". auto_ptrs are only good for what 20.4.5/3 says they are good for.

Comment: Let me add to this that you should, by all means, replace auto_ptr by unique_ptr in your code and fix the compilation errors. You'd be surprised how many bugs this will uncover.

Answer (score 42):

Herb Sutter has a nice explanation on [GotW #89](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/):

> **What’s the deal with auto_ptr?** auto_ptr is most charitably characterized as a valiant attempt to create a unique_ptr before C++
>   had move semantics. auto_ptr is now deprecated, and should not be used
>   in new code.
>
> If you have auto_ptr in an existing code base, when you get a chance
>   try doing a global search-and-replace of auto_ptr to unique_ptr; the
>   vast majority of uses will work the same, and it might expose (as a
>   compile-time error) or fix (silently) a bug or two you didn't know you
>   had.

In other words, while a global search-and-replace may "break" your code temporarily, you should do it anyway: It may take some time to fix the compile errors, but will save you a lot more trouble in the long run.

Comment: Great link. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 37):

AFAIK, `unique_ptr` is not a direct replacement. The major flaw  that it fixes is the implicit transfer of ownership.

```
std::auto_ptr<int> a(new int(10)), b;
b = a; //implicitly transfers ownership

std::unique_ptr<int> a(new int(10)), b;
b = std::move(a); //ownership must be transferred explicitly
```

On the other hand, `unique_ptr` will have completely new capabilities: they can be stored in containers.

Comment: Scott Meyers also mentioned in his "Effective C++" (3rd Edition) Item 13 (page 64) that STL containers require that their contents exhibit "normal" copying behavior, so containers of `auto_ptr` aren't allowed.