# What is the proper way to return an object from a C++ function?

Tags: c++, pointers, object, reference

I am confused between :

- returning an **object** (but then the object is copied from the local variable in the function, which consumes memory)
- returning a **pointer** (but then you have to remember to delete it, in the calling code, which is weird)
- returning a **reference** (but this is not possible because this would be a reference to a local variable of the function, which would be deleted as soon as the function ends)

I am looking for the proper way to return an object from a C++ function, in basic C++ (no library handling pointers and freeing memory automatically). I want to know how this is supposed to be done.

Thank you

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350385/how-to-return-an-object-in-c

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate, the search didn't bring that out when I tried

Comment: That's alright. The search on SO is...lacking.

Comment: @GMan: I'm not sure this is an exact duplicate. The other one is asking in light of (premature) optimization, while this one seems to be asking how to return _in general_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modern compilers typically implement the [(Named) Return Value Optimization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057(VS.80).aspx), by which the copy you reference (and would logically expect) is not done.

Ever since Visual Studio 2005 (VC++ 8.0) I don't think twice about returning objects.

Comment: oh ! gcc too ? It seems like a "trick"... C++ just seems wrong :(

Comment: +1: Trust your compiler, RVO/NRVO are very effective at their job.

Comment: gcc and intel too, yes. Every compiler worth its salt does this.

Comment: OK this seems like "the" answer. But it's so weird so many people don't seem to know that (look at the other answers)... it keeps the confusion alive. Thank you anyway !

Comment: @Matthieu - I did not know about this myself until I was trying to work out why Visual C++ 7.1 code was spending so much time in object copying.  Just moving to Visual C++ 8.0 made it measurably faster, and I wanted to find out why.

Comment: @Matthieu (like your name ;)) In fact, gcc is more aggressive that VC++ in this regard, since it performs this optimization even in at -O0. It's just that common.

Answer (score 3):

What about `std::auto_ptr` from `<memory>`? Or if C++0x is concerned `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: I think he's asking about more fundamental patterns.

Comment: @quixoto: Well do provide them :)

Comment: I don't have a great answer here, was watching the question myself.

Answer (score 3):

A few rules of thumb regarding returning objects from functions:

Return ***per copy***, except when

1. you return ***a non-local object*** (like a class member, static variable etc.) of a type that you would [pass to a function per `const` reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c/2139254#2139254); you can return this ***per `const` reference***
2. you return ***a non-local object*** and callers should be able to ***invoke modifying members*** of the returned object, thereby manipulating an object stored elsewhere; return this ***per non-`const` reference***
3. you return ***a derived class in a polymorphic class hierarchy***, users of the object should only know the base class, and neither #1 nor #2 apply; return this ***per smart pointer***

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "no library handling pointers and freeing memory automatically" means no return-by-pointer, no `boost::shared_ptr` and no `std::unique_ptr` (`std::auto_ptr` is [evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451099/stdauto-ptr-to-stdunique-ptr) anyway), you have two choices:

Return by value:

```
Foo bar(quux)
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.frobnicate(quux);
    return foo;
}

Foo foo = bar("fred");
```

Pass by reference:

```
void bar(Foo& foo, quux)
{
    foo.frobnicate(quux);
}

Foo foo;
bar(foo, "fred");
```

Comment: +1 for the "explicit object in caller, reference outparam" pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the "semantics" of the object. Values should be returned by copy while entities should (or *must*, since they are ideally not copyable) be returned by pointer or reference.

References should be used when possible. But if you must return a pointer, using a smart pointer class such as std::auto_ptr or boost::shared_ptr is a good idea, because then the calling code don't have to wonder about freeing it when it is done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Return by value unless you need subtype polymorphism. In the latter case, I would return an `auto_ptr<T>` (C++03) or a `unique_ptr<T>` (C++0x).

Answer (score 0):

- Return one of the smart pointer choices (either having to depends on extra libraries or wait until C++1x)
- Use pass by reference

Personally I prefer the second option because it is clear that the user needs to allocate and delete memory.

Comment: Is C++0x done? I know some compilers support parts of it now, but it isn't finalised is it?

Comment: @PhilCK: No we all HOPE it will be finalized next year. Though some believe that 2012 is more realistic.

Comment: Hence the 1x. Some says that it will eventually be 2x -_- I certainly hope not.

Comment: @PhilCK: The final committee draft was approved in March.  It is fully expected that only small bugfixes and edits will occur from now on.  It's likely to pass as ISO C++11 next year, and will not be substantially different than the FCD that's already out.

Answer (score 0):

> returning an object (but then the
>   object is copied from the local
>   variable in the function, which
>   consumes memory)

Optimal compilers may not take significant time to create copy.
You may also need to implement copy constructor and overload assignment operator, depending upon your object contents.

> returning a pointer (but then you have
>   to remember to delete it, in the
>   calling code, which is weird)

Yes, you have to remember to delete it as you do not want to consider automatic cleanup for this question.

> returning a reference (but this is not
>   possible because this would be a
>   reference to a local variable of the
>   function, which would be deleted as
>   soon as the function ends)

Returning reference is useful when you are returning this object(*this) from member functions. Otherwise, like you mentioned its not possible to use.

Overall: it depends upon your need as described above regarding which one to choose when.