# Difference between "MyClass& func1(void)" and "MyClass* func2(void)"

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the proper way to return an object from a C++ function ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953637/what-is-the-proper-way-to-return-an-object-from-a-c-function)

Hi there,

i would like to know whats the difference between the following two functions with respect to the return types?

1. MyClass& func1(void)
2. MyClass* func2(void)

I always thought this would be the same?

Heinrich

Comment: one returns reference, latter pointer, http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/references.html

Comment: @sbi this question seems different from that. This one seems like "What is the difference between pointing at a cake and eating it? I thought that is the same!" and the other one seems like "What should I do when I want a piece of cake from my friend? Ask him or just eat it away?". Nothing in the pointed to question (no pun intended) answers this question. I rather downvoted this one, because it's "Not A Real Question". What difference? The lexical one? "One uses & the other uses *". The syntactic one? "One uses a reference the other uses a pointer". The use-case of the two?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. so if I create a std::map<MyClass&, AType> this will insert references to the objects, not pointers, nor copy the objects itself, right?

Comment: std::map<MyClass&, AType> isnt correct, references are not copyable (there are other restrictions as well, read FAQ).

Comment: So I could make: std::map<MyClass*, AType> ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is only capable of returning a reference to a single object and may not be null. Or rather, it should not be null.

The second one may be returning the pointer to a single object, or an array of objects.

In cases where you wish to return a single object that cannot be null, #1 tends to be the preferred form. In cases where a null can be returned #2 has to be used. Some APIs don't return references at all (like QT).

This is strictly a syntactic difference however. These two types are handled exactly the same in the compiled code: a pointer to the object (or array) will be used. That is, strictly speaking, the reference notation & adds no new semantic functionality over a normal pointer.

(This perhaps just summarizes what the other people wrote)

Answer (score 1):

the first one returns reference to an object (or its address). The other one returns pointer, not reference

Major difference: the second one can return `NULL`

Comment: Another major one, the second one can return a pointer into an entire array of objects.

Comment: You can also return a null reference, but that is quite ugly.

Comment: There's no such thing.. NULL reference.. you could return 0x00,which is address zero,but it's not NULL ref.