# C++. Return an object or pass a reference to be filled?

Tags: c++, reference, return, return-value

*Hello. I looked for an answer but did not found it for this specific question.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953637/what-is-the-proper-way-to-return-an-object-from-a-c-function) I found an [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057(VS.80).aspx) which shows how the Visual C++ compiler eliminates redundant Copy constructor and Destructor calls in various situations. I believe the same is true for Clang and GCC.*

There are two structs: input data `Waveform` and result `Analyzed`. And two functions do the same work but returns a result in different ways. 1st creates a local `Analyzed` and returns it (copy), 2nd takes reference to an already created object to fill it, returns the same.

```
struct Waveform;
struct Analyzed;

Analyzed  analyze( Waveform const& wf );  // Form 1
Analyzed& analyze( Waveform const& wf, Analyzed& an );  // Form 2
```

Example usage, assuming `Waveform wf` already in scope:

```
auto an0 = analyze(wf);
Analyzed const& an1 = analyze(wf);

Analyzed an3;
analyze(wf,an3);
```

As for me *Form 1* is shorter and more convenient.

As far as I know, in `C` a good practice considered passing to function pointers to a prealloated memory (so user is responsible for memory) and not to return objects bigger than `sizeof(int)`, but return pointer or error number.

**The question.** Is one of the `analyze()` forms better? Why?
Is there any performance issues, extra copies, pitfalls?
Any special cases?

---

I also can imagine how *Form 1* reuses *Form 2*:

```
Analyzed  analyze( Waveform const& wf ){
  Analyzed an;
  analyze(wf,an);
  return an;
}
```

---

< spoiler >
**Longer** description. 
There are two structs: `Waveform` represents a signal, and `Analyzed` - characteristics of the signal.

```
struct Waveform {
  size_t len;
  float *arr;
  float sampleRate;
  //...
}

struct Analyzed {
  struct Entry { size_t idx; float value; };
  Entry max;
  Entry min;
  float peakToPeak;
  float mean;
  //...
};

Analyzed  analyze( Waveform const& wf );
Analyzed& analyze( Waveform const& wf, Analyzed& an );
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with C tag.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I have added C tag because "... in C a good practice considered passing..."

Comment: That's OK, but IMHO the tag does not belong here.\

Comment: There's a lot of languages out there, each with its own best practices. There's no reason to single out C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This form is preferred by many people now:

```
auto a = analyze(wf);
```

It's simple to write and simple to understand; nothing can go wrong.  The C++17 draft specification includes guarantees that no intermediate temporary objects will be involved; C++14 made that optional. Most compilers did take up the option.

If you compare this with:

```
Analyzed an;
analyze(wf, an);
```

two of the major differences are:

- It's not clear just from reading the code whether the function argument is an "in", "out", or "in-out" parameter. You'd have to look up the documentation.
- This won't even work at all if `Analyzed` has no default-constructor.  Which is not uncommon; it's following good object-oriented principles to have a constructor set an object up; as opposed to having the constructor make a dummy shell that will get "initialized" later.

Both of which make the code less easy to understand and more likely to have coding mistakes associated with them.