# unique_ptr VS auto_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [std::auto_ptr to std::unique_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451099/stdauto-ptr-to-stdunique-ptr)
>   [What C++ Smart Pointer Implementations are available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026197/what-c-smart-pointer-implementations-are-available)

Lets say I have this `struct`:

```
struct bar 
{ 

};
```

When I use **auto_ptr** like this:

```
void foo() 
{ 
   auto_ptr<bar> myFirstBar = new bar; 
   if( ) 
   { 
     auto_ptr<bar> mySecondBar = myFirstBar; 
   } 
}
```

then at `auto_ptr<bar> mySecondBar = myFirstBar;` C++ transfers the ownership from myFirstBar to mySecondBar and there is no compilation error.

But when I use **unique_ptr** instead of **auto_ptr** I get a compiler error. Why C++ doesn't allow this? And what is the main differences between these two smart pointers? When I need to use what?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026197/what-c-smart-pointer-implementations-are-available

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`std::auto_ptr<T>` may silently steal the resource. This can be confusing and it was tried to defined `std::auto_ptr<T>` to not let you do this. With `std::unique_ptr<T>` ownership won't be silently transferred from anything you still hold. It transfers ownership only from objects you don't have a handle to (temporaries) or which are about to go away (object about to go out of scope in a function). If you really want to transfer ownership, you'd use `std::move()`:

```
std::unique_ptr<bar> b0(new bar());
std::unique_ptr<bar> b1(std::move(b0));
```

Comment: Minor comment, the first line should be `new bar`, not `new std::unique_ptr<bar>`

Comment: I think "Silent Transfer" is the problem with auto_ptr.