# Implicit conversions and copy constructors

Tags: c++

**Update:** The [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956693/why-c-copy-constructor-must-use-const-object) only addresses part of this question. The key to understand what is going on (the fact that a temporary reference is first created) isn't explained there.

This is my first time with implicit conversions, so I wrote this:

```
class A {};

class B {
public:
    B(A& other) {}
    // Copy constructor
    B(const B& other) {}
};

int main() {
    A foo;
    B bar = foo;
}
```

This compiles as expected, but if I remove the `const`, my compiler (gcc version 4.8.4) yields at the assignment, with an error message I'm not able to make sense of:

```
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:12:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘B::B(B)’
     B bar = foo;
             ^
test.cc:12:13: note: candidates are:
test.cc:7:5: note: B::B(B&)
     B(B& other) {}
     ^
test.cc:7:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘B’ to ‘B&’
test.cc:5:5: note: B::B(A&)
     B(A& other) {}
     ^
test.cc:5:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘B’ to ‘A&’
```

Is that valid C++ code? Why does it say `no matching function for call to ‘B::B(B)’` when I'm trying to assign an `A` to begin with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why C++ copy constructor must use const object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956693/why-c-copy-constructor-must-use-const-object)

Comment: This must have something to do with the move operator, because `B bar( foo );`works with no complain if `const` is removed.

Comment: Interesting that removing `const` works under gcc 4.1.2.

Comment: @dbush not sure that compiler must provide diagnostics when copy ctor call is eliminated by optimization, but language requires it's accessibility

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`B bar = foo` is called *copy-initialization*: When the type of the right hand side doesn't match the type of the left hand side (in this case, a `B` vs `A`) the compiler creates a temporary initialized from the right hand side and then copies it using the copy-constructor. This is effectively your code:

```
B bar = B(foo);
```

Since you've removed `const` from your copy-constructor, you now get an error because you're trying to bind an rvalue to an lvalue reference. Rvalues can bind to `const` lvalue references as you've already seen.

This can be resolved by using *direct-initialization*. Now no copy is being created:

```
B bar(foo);
```

Comment: Sidenote: it was [this tutorial in cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting) (see example in second section) that gave me the idea that the conversion constructor was called directly.

Comment: @jmendeth Indeed, cplusplus is not the best tutorial website. I can also see it was mistaken about the "three" member functions that allow conversions. There's only two, a converting constructor (one argument constructor) and a conversion operator. The assignment operator is just another member function and has nothing to do with conversions.

Answer (score 7):

This declaration

```
B bar = foo;
```

works the following way:

At first the compiler creates a temporary object using constructor:

```
B(A& other) {}
```

then it tries to use this temporary object in the copy constructor:

```
B(B& other) {}
```

But it may not bind a temporary object with non-constant reference and it issues an error.

When you are using the equal sign then there is used so-called copy-initialization.

If you wrote

```
B bar( foo );
```

then here would used so-called direct initialization that is the copy constructor is not called. In this case this code will compile.

Take into account that the copy/move constructor may be bypassed and the temporary object can be built directly in the destination object. This is called *copy elision*. Nevertheless the all rules shall be kept as if the copy/move constructor is called explicitly.

For example if you add output statements for the constructors of class B

```
class A {};

class B {
public:
    B(A& other) { std::cout << "B::B( A & )" << std::endl; }
    // Copy constructor
    B(const B& other) { std::cout << "B::B( const B & )" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A foo;
    B bar = foo;
}
```

then you will not see the message

```
B::B( const B & )
```

However the copy constructor shall be accessible.

For example if you make it private

```
class A {};

class B {
public:
    B(A& other) { std::cout << "B::B( A & )" << std::endl; }
    // Copy constructor
private:
    B(const B& other) { std::cout << "B::B( const B & )" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A foo;
    B bar = foo;
}
```

the program won't compile (only if it is not the MS VC++ compiler.:) )

Comment: I think you should mention that copy constructor may not actually be called semantics require it's accessibility anyway.

Comment: @Slava I appended my post.

Comment: Great answer! Still, accepting @0x499602D2 because it seems clearer and easier to understand to me.