# C++ old struct operator overloading syntax changed?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am building my old CPP codes from 20+ years ago, but g++ gives build error.  Can someone explains me what has changed?  Thanks.  (It was fine in turbo C)

error:

```
t_overload.cpp:8:40: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Point'
    Point operator+(Point& v) { return Point(x+v.x, y+v.y); }
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

cpp file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Point {
    int x, y;
//    Point(Point& v) {set(v.x, v.y);}     // build okay without this line; error if uncomment
    Point(int a, int b) {set(a,b);}
    void set(int a, int b) {x=a, y=b;}
    Point operator+(Point& v) { return Point(x+v.x, y+v.y); }
};

int main() {
    Point a(1,2);
    Point b(a);

    Point c = a + b;
    printf("%d %d\n", c.x, c.y);
}
```

Comment: This question is closed for the reason of duplicating another one: "copy constructor must use const object".  Actually the error here complained within the operator overloading.  Instead of jumping to the conclusion saying they are the same problem, a better elaborating why they are the same is more helpful, as in Sam's answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate because the [accepted answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16956812/10957435) third point is exactly what you're running into. Sorry if I left you confused. Confusion was certainly not my intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Point(Point& v)
```

Copy constructors should take `const`ant parameters, this should be:

```
Point(const Point& v)
```

But given what that copy constructor does, it's completely unnecessary. You can get rid of it, completely.

```
Point operator+(Point& v)
```

Similarly, the parameter to the overload should be constant:

```
Point operator+(const Point& v)
```

See ["What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Both of these issues, together with rather nuanced and delicate rules of overloading and how temporaries bind to function parameters, were resulting in your compilation errors.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.  Changing the copy constructor argument to const fixed the error.  (The question is locked.  I can't upvote..)