# Stack overflow error when having an assignment operator and a copy constructor

Tags: c++

I have an error with an assignment operator and copy constructor. It shows a stack overflow error in Visual Studio 2022.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    int* x;
    A copy(const A& other)
    {
        x = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            x[i] = other.x[i];
        return *this;
    }

public:
    A()
    {
        x = new int[10];
    }
    A(A& other)
    {
        copy(other);
    }
    const A& operator=(const A& other)
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            delete[]x;
            copy(other);
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A o1, o2;
    o1 = o2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think about what happens when your `copy` function returns `*this` *by value* (and create a *copy*)...

Comment: Also note that your copy constructor should take a `const` reference

Comment: oh it will go to infinite thank you so much

Comment: why it should ?

Comment: To be able to accept const and/or temporary objects. Why did you write `const` in the copy assignment but not in the copy constructor?

Comment: I notice a very distinct absence of a destructor in this class, so memory leakage is guaranteed. Also, if you're going to hard-code an array of 10 integers, why not make `x` an array instead of a pointer?

Comment: @Mohamad_T See https://stackoverflow.com/q/16956693/580083

Comment: `=` should be `A & operator=(const A& other)`, ie no `const` on the return. On the other hand, your `copy` doesnt need chaning, it can return `void`

Comment: "why it should?" because `other` is not modified.

Comment: Why not replace `x = new int[10];`  with  `std::vector<int>` it will avoid a lot of your problems

Answer (score 0):

The comments answered your particular question, but there are a few other issues you may want to consider.

If you define a copy constructor and copy assignment operator, you
probably also need to define a destrcutor. This is known as the [rule
of three/five](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172724/1202808). In the
posted code that means you need a destructor to delete the allocated
memory.

Also, in order to ensure exception safety, you may also want to
consider using the [copy and swap
idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279550/1202808). This also allows
the copy assignment operator to be written in terms of the copy
constructor eliminating the need to write a separate `copy` function
that is used by both.

Lastly, in modern `C++` there are very few instances that call for
using raw pointers. Since this class presumably owns the data in `x`,
a `std::unique_ptr` would accurately indicate the intended owership
and simplify managing the memory.

### Sample Code

```cpp
// Rule of three with copy-and-swap idiom
class A {
public:
    A() {
        x = new int[10];
    }

    A(const A& other) : A() {
        std::copy(other.x, other.x + 10, x);
    }

    const A& operator=(A other) {
        std::swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }

    ~A() {
        delete x;
    }

private:
    int *x{nullptr};
};

// Copy-and-swap idiom using a unique pointer
class AUP {
public:
    AUP() {
        x = std::make_unique<int[]>(10);
    }

    AUP(const AUP& other) : AUP() {
        std::copy(other.x.get(), other.x.get() + 10, x.get());
    }

    const AUP& operator=(AUP other) {
        std::swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> x;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    A b = a;
    AUP aup;
    AUP bup = aup;
}
```