# C++ Qt where's the std::unique_ptr Qt version?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

So when programming in Qt I like to go with the Qt implementation as far as possible.
As far as I've seen there's no Qt version of the `std::unique_ptr` or is there?

What would be the alternatives that produce the "same" result in Qt if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Why do you specifically want a Qt version? Are you trying to write C++ without a standard library?

Comment: @MikeSeymour not particularly but there's no need for mixing the std with Qt when the Qt implementation covers it all :)

Comment: @deW1 : That's not how it works, the STL is something you should use every time when it solve your problem. It's just so well written that any other library can't be as effective as STL is. I suggest you to only use Qt implementation for things, that doesn't have a solution already in the STL.

Comment: *"It's just so well written that any other library can't be as effective as STL is."* -- Err, that's a bit of a stretch. Although I would agree that it does most things as good or better than Qt (at least for my purposes), for those things which both Qt and the standard library do.

Comment: Well, i wrote it as a general rule, there can be some exception, but i believe that trying to avoid STL doesn't make much sense.

Comment: To counter the points about using the std library/STL, I'd argue that consistency increases readability, which is important for maintaining code. So if you're using `QSharedPointer` and `QVector` and `QMap` etc throughout your code, throwing in a single `std::unique_ptr` might throw a reader off if you could instead use `QScopedPointer`.

Comment: I feel that this misses the point of why QT containers continue to exist and were not obsoleted by the STL.  QT-based Objects cannot be copied or moved as their operators are deleted by design so they need specialized containers.  Part of this is to ensure that signals and slots targeting a QObject can still function however, the restriction makes some of the containers a little less than optimal.  It's my opinion that you should use the right class or structure for the job instead of being uniform just for the sake of being uniform.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The Qt equivalent to `std::unique_ptr` is [`QScopedPointer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qscopedpointer.html).

It's significantly less useful as it doesn't support move semantics, making it closer in utility to C++03 [`std::auto_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr) ([Why is auto_ptr being deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697686/what-is-the-problem-with-auto-ptr)).

Comment: `QScopedPointer` isn't broken like `auto_ptr` is it? It doesn't transfer ownership on copy and assignment, it just doesn't support copy and assignment. (afaict, reading the documentation)

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley indeed, it doesn't have a copy constructor at all, not even a non-const one.

Comment: TBH it does have custom deleters, which auto_ptr didn't have.

Comment: `QScopedPointer<T>` is probably closer to `const std::unique_ptr<T>` than to anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The `std::unique_ptr` and the now deprecated `std::auto_ptr`, can be used to "force" that the pointed-value is not changed after `return`.

Like in one of my projects, our library provided an `Interface`, where we wanted to restrict user-implemented version of said interface, to ensure they don't accidentally change `MyType`'s value later (after `return`), like:

```
struct MyType { /* ... */ };

typedef std::unique_ptr<MyType> MyTypeUniquePtr;

class MyLibInterface {
public:
    virtual ~MyLibInterface();

    virtual MyTypeUniquePtr doSomething() = 0;
};
```

If said "return" or restriction is NOT needed by your code, then the `QScopedPointer` class can be used to ensure resources get released once scope ends, like if `throw` happens.

But that's it, `QScopedPointer` uses `Q_DISABLE_COPY`, hence move-constructor gets forbidden as well (if compiler is sane), and `return` should cause compile error.

There is no class fully-equivalent to `std::unique_ptr` in original Qt, hence if your target tool-chains/ compilers all support `std::unique_ptr`, simply use that, however, I may add `QUniquePointer` to my [XD](https://github.com/top-master/XD) framework, just to support *more* compilers (more, not all).