# Warning linking libxml++-2.6 (c++11 obsoltes std::auto_ptr). Shall I just ignore it?

Tags: c++11, auto-ptr

Using gcc with -std=c++11

```
pkg-config libxml++-2.6 --modversion
```

2.40.1

get lots of warnings like this:
/usr/include/libxml++-2.6/libxml++/parsers/saxparser.h:224:8: warning: 'template class std::auto_ptr' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

1. I may follow the recommendation and disable this warning but I may miss other warnings in future.
2. I may try latest libxml++ version 2.91; despite huge minor(lol) version difference it's at most one month younger; I'll build this on older machines where libxml++ will probably be older.

I'll ignore this warning. Would anybody do otherwise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be safe ignoring the `std::auto_ptr` warning. Prior to C++11, [`auto_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr) was a common way to manage memory, because it takes ownership of a pointer. Post C++11 it's recommended to use the new smart pointers that are part of STL (ie [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111478/why-is-it-wrong-to-use-stdauto-ptr-with-standard-containers) has a good discussion on `std::auto_ptr` and issues that led to it being [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697686/why-is-auto-ptr-being-deprecated). I wouldn't write new code using it, but existing code using `auto_ptr` should be safe (assuming there aren't bugs to begin with which may or may not be valid).

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a better-than-average chance that `auto_ptr` [will be removed from C++17](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/11/updates-to-my-trip-report). So I would be at least somewhat concerned about relying on software that made use of it.

Comment: It seems it's already fixed into latest version. The NEWS file states for 
        version2.91.1 (unstable):
        * Replace the deprecated std::auto_ptr by std::unique_ptr

Answer (score 0):

You could replace your libxml++ version by a version higher or equal than 2.9.1 They fixed the auto_ptr thing and replaced it by unique_ptr. Although you have to install libxml++-2.9.1 by hand by downloading it from:

http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/libxml++/

hope it helps.