# Example of C++ std::vector<std::auto_ptr<T>> that compiles but fails

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr, auto-ptr

What would be a simple C++ program where a `std::vector<std::auto_ptr<T>>` compiles but fails to execute correctly, whereas the same program with `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` compiles and works correctly, for some data type `T`?

I know that `std::auto_ptr` has been deprecated or removed; I just want an example involving containers to motivate *why* it was deprecated or removed.

I'm using `g++-10 -std=c++20` on MacOS Big Sur version 11.2.1.

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated and one of the main reason - it does not work with containers

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697686/why-is-auto-ptr-being-deprecated  That question has several answers with examples.

Answer (score 6):

`std::auto_ptr` simply cannot be used in standard containers at all.  It does not maintain proper semantics under that situation.  Which is one of the reasons why move semantics and `std::unique_ptr` were invented in C++11 in the first place.  `std::auto_ptr` was deprecated in C++11, and removed completely in C++17.  So don't use it at all in modern coding.

The official reason why `std::auto_ptr` was deprecated is detailed here:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1856.html#20.4.5%20-%20Class%20template%20auto_ptr

The example given uses `std::sort()` on a `std::vector<std::auto_ptr<int>>`:

> With such a design, one could put auto_ptr into a container:
>
> ```cpp
> vector<auto_ptr<int> > vec;
> ```
>
> However field experience with this design revealed subtle problems. Namely:
>
> ```cpp
> sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), indirect_less());
> ```
>
> Depending upon the implementation of `sort`, the above line of reasonable looking code may or may not execute as expected, and may even **crash**! The problem is that some implementations of `sort` will pick an element out of the sequence, and store a local *copy* of it.
>
> ```cpp
> ...
> value_type pivot_element = *mid_point;
> ...
> ```
>
> The algorithm assumed that after this construction that `pivot_element` and `*mid_point` were equivalent. However when `value_type` turned out to be an `auto_ptr`, this assumption failed, and subsequently so did the algorithm.
>
> The fix to this problem was to make `auto_ptr` inhospitable to containers by disallowing "copying" from a `const auto_ptr`. With such an `auto_ptr`, one gets a compile time error if you try to put it in a container.

The conclusion at the end comes down to this:

> Calling any generic code, whether `std` or not, that will operate on `auto_ptr` is risky because the generic code may assume that something that looks like a copy operation, actually *is* a copy operation.
>
> Conclusion:
>
> One should not move from lvalues using copy syntax. Other syntax for moving should be used instead. Otherwise generic code is likely to initiate a move when a copy was intended.
>
> **`auto_ptr` moves from lvalues using copy syntax and is thus fundamentally unsafe.**

Comment: The question is specifically asking for an example in which using of `std::auto_ptr` compiles but fails to execute correctly. It remains to be seen whether that's an appropriate question for SO or not. :-)

Comment: I mean, the first sentence straight-up answers the question. Is a code example really necessary?

Comment: Thank you, Remy Lebeau, your example of copying the pivot element in  a Quicksort shows very clearly why a container of std::auto_ptr<T> could fail to execute correctly.  But then how could a container of std::unique_ptr<T> possibly work correctly with this Quicksort?  My type_traits gave identical answers for auto_ptr and unique_ptr (I tried is_copy_constructible, is_move_constructible, is_assignable, is_move_assignable), so how could an algorithm such as a Quicksort tell the difference between auto_ptr and unique_ptr?  Thanks again.

Comment: @MarkMeretzky it doesn't have to. When unique_ptr was introduced, the requirements of sort() were also updated to require the algorithm to support move semantics on the values of dereferenced iterators.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `auto_ptr` is that it can be copied and making a copy modifies the original:

```
a = b;   // transfers ownership from b to a
```

This is similar to what moving does now, just that at the time of `auto_ptr` there was no move semantics in the language. Now that C++ has move semantics transfer of ownership can be expressed more clearly:

```
a = std::move(b);
```

Nobody would/should expect that `b` is not modified in that line.

However, with `a = b` it is commonly assumed, that `b` is not modified. `auto_ptr` breaks that assumption. Consider for example:

```
template <typename P>
void foo() {
    std::vector<P> x;
    x.resize(42);
    int i=0;
    for (auto& e : x) e.reset(new int(i++));
    
    for (auto e : x) {
        std::cout << *e << "\n";        
    }
    for (auto e : x) {
        std::cout << *e << "\n";        
    }    
}
```

With `P=std::unique_ptr<int>` this will cause [a compiler error](https://godbolt.org/z/aez3dr):

```
<source>:17:15: error: call to deleted constructor of 'std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >'
    for (auto e : x) {
              ^ ~
```

While it compiles with `P=std::auto_ptr<int>` but is undefined behavior (eg segfault here: https://godbolt.org/z/93hdse), because it dereferences null pointers.

Similar issue with any algorithm assumes it is "ok" to copy elements. For example a comparator for `auto_ptr` that takes parameters by value does compile but causes havoc:

```
auto compare = [](auto a,auto b) { return *a < *b; }
std::sort(x.begin(), x.end(),compare);   // BOOM !
```

Not always is it so obvious that a copy is being made, algorithms may copy elements internally when elements are copyable.