# Why was the std::pair class standard changed to disallow types with only a nonconstant copy constructor in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, move-semantics

I am reading through Nicolai M. Josuttis' "The C++ Standard Library (Second Edition)" and have just reached the section on `std::pair`. The author notes that:

> Since C++11, a `pair<>` using a type that has only a nonconstant copy constructor will no longer compile.

He then goes on to give the following example:

```
class A 
{
   public:
     ...
     A( A& ); // copy constructor with nonconstant reference
     ...
};

std::pair<A, int> p; // Error since C++11
```

However, I'm interested in the reason that the standards committee decided to make this amendment to the standard library standard? I tried to google the reason, but was unsuccessful in finding anything pertinent.

Comment: I would have to guess it was always meant to use const to promise to the user to preserve the contents of the pair, and C++11 was able to fit that in the actual standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++98, copy constructors with non-constant reference parameters would be [(ab)used to "move" elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683959/can-a-copy-constructor-take-a-non-const-parameter) around. Such code was notoriously unsafe and unclear. The infamous and now [deprecated `std::auto_ptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404115/is-auto-ptr-deprecated) was the prime example of that.

In C++11, we have [move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics) and rvalue references to achieve the same effects much more safely and clearly. This is because an rvalue reference is a reference to a mutable object, but it can only bind to "safe" expressions such as temporaries or things that you have explicitly cast (via `std::move`) and thus marked as disposable.

In short: classes with copy constructors taking non-reference members have no real use cases that cannot be done better and safer with rvalue references. `std::pair` acquired a move constructor `std::pair(std::pair&&)=default` to accomodate such semantics.